# Returning reference to a singleton class instance within its functions

Tags: kotlin

In the following code I would like to set a reference to the class instance so that static functions can return a reference to it:

```
open class TestRunner {

    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: TestRunner

        fun addTestSetups(vararg testSetups: () -> TestSetup): TestRunner {
           for (setup in testSetups) {
              testsSetups.add(setup)
           }

           return instance
        }
    }
}
```

But setting `instance = this` is not allowed. How can I return an instance of the class from a function while keeping the class as a singleton?

Comment: Remove the init block from the companion object. In this block, `this` is the companion object, which is not a TestRunner, but a TestRunner.Companion (as the error message tells)

Comment: Sorry, I pasted that code without first removing it. I had actually removed it. I corrected the code above, but the question remains the same.

Comment: This code compiles fine (except for the undefined variables and classes). What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead? Be precise. Include any complete and exact error message you get.

Comment: In the function addTestSetups, it returns TestRunner. I do this to allow the chaining of functions. But for chaining to work, I need a reference to the class instance. So the "instance" variable needs to be set.

Comment: Setting instance = this **is** allowed. So what is your question? Post the relevant code. Tell what are you doing, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead? Be precise. Include any complete and exact error message you get.

Comment: Yes, setting instance = this is allowed, except init will never be called.

Comment: It will be called if you call the constructor of TestRunner, or of any of its subclasses. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to create a singleton, all you need is `object TestRunner { ... }`. Your class is currently not a singleton at all since you can create as many instances of it, or of any subclass, as you like.

Comment: I need a singleton that can be inherited from. Hence "open class TestRunner". You cannot use open with just object. You're right about it not being a singleton but it's the closest I can get while allowing the functions to be static.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Instead of keeping a variable that holds a reference to the class, simply referencing the name of the class is sufficient. However, to return an instance of the class from functions, the return type must be Companion:

```
open class TestRunner {
    companion object {
        fun addTestSetups(vararg testSetups: () -> TestSetup): Companion {
           for (setup in testSetups) {
              testsSetups.add(setup)
           }

           return TestRunner
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a true singleton because you can still create a new instance if you did this:

```
val testRunner = TestRunner()
```

However, if you never create an instance but only refer to the functions statically, it does behave like a singleton and the state of any private variables inside the companion object will still be maintained.

**Update:**

I came across this code on the Android developer site that shows an example of a class that is setup as a singleton:

```
class StockLiveData(symbol: String) : LiveData<BigDecimal>() {
    private val stockManager: StockManager = StockManager(symbol)

    private val listener = { price: BigDecimal ->
        value = price
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        stockManager.requestPriceUpdates(listener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        stockManager.removeUpdates(listener)
    }

    companion object {
        private lateinit var sInstance: StockLiveData

        @MainThread
        fun get(symbol: String): StockLiveData {
            sInstance = if (::sInstance.isInitialized) sInstance else StockLiveData(symbol)
            return sInstance
        }
    }
}
```

But it should be pointed out that this example requires functions that need to return an instance to first check if the instance variable is set and if not, create a new instance. I'm not sure what the point of that is since to call the function you already have an instance. So why bother create a new instance? Doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: In your top example, you can't inherit the functions of the companion object if you subclass TestRunner. Companion objects aren't part of the outer class definition. They're just singletons that can conveniently be referred to by the name of that outer class.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want something like this:

```
abstract class TestRunner {
    companion object : TestRunner()
}
```

Comment: Nope. Abstract classes have no implementation. I just wanted to return a reference to the class instance in functions. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

`object` in Kotlin is the singleton, not the class its defined within. A companion object has the extra convenience of allowing you to call it by the name of that outer class. But it otherwise shares no hierarchy with it.

To make your class subclassable, you can't define the functions in the companion object. But you can make the class abstract so it can't be instantiated unless subclassed. Then make your companion object extend the abstract class so it will have all those functions available.

```
abstract class TestRunner{
    open fun addTestSetups(vararg testSetups: () -> TestSetup): TestRunner{
        //...
        return this
    }

    companion object: TestRunner()
}
```

Usage:

```
TestRunner.addTestSetups(someTestSetup)
```

Note that your singleton is not an instance of TestRunner. It is a singleton instance of a subclass of TestRunner. But since you define no extra functions and override nothing, it behaves exactly like a TestRunner.

If you want a subclass:

```
abstract class ExtendedTestRunner: TestRunner() {

    fun someOtherFunction() {}

    companion object: ExtendedTestRunner()
}
```

The companions are not being subclassed, but their abstract parents can be.